# How can I change name of button when I touch textField?

Tags: ios, button, uitextfield, touch

I know that it is a simple question, but I do not know how can I do that. I mean I need use gesture or some method and which one? I tried this with FirstResponder and touch events but all they are works not how I need. And title of button need to be changed only in one way - when I touch textField. Sorry for my english.

Comment: When you say "name" of button, do you actually mean the "title" displayed on the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `UITextField` Delegate :

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender{  
 //[sender resignFirstResponder];// Resigning the KeyBoard.
 [self.myButton setTitle:@"ddd" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Why would you dismiss the keyboard just as the text field is becoming the first responder?

Comment: The OP is just asking for the touch event and may be the thought is for different purpose.

Comment: Remove this line **[sender resignFirstResponder];**

Comment: I got, thanks. No need [sender resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
[YourTextField addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(yourDesiredMethod) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)yourDesiredMethod
{
    [YourButton setTitle:@"YourTitleString" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```